# Solving the discrete logarithm using index calculus, finite fields and factor bases.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, cryptography

(a) Let $p$ be the prime 1073741827, with $\Bbb{F}_p$ the corresponding finite field.  A primitive root in $\Bbb{F}_p$ is equal to $g=2$.  Use a factor base of primes up to 13 to find the discrete logarithm of 1000173298.  You should compute powers of g modulo p using Magma (or other program) and use the index calculus method.

(b) Let p be the prime 34359738421, with $\Bbb{F}_p$ the corresponding finite field.  A primitive root in $\Bbb{F}_p$ is equal to $g=2$.  Experiment with various factor bases to see what size factor base would likely allow you to determine the discrete logarithm of 7164430421. (You are not asked to find the discrete logarithm, unless you wish to.)

Comment: Well, what did you learn during your Magma session?

Comment: Hint: $2^{30}=p-3$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  We focused mostly on theory and not quantitatively solving these problems in the class, and I am not familiar with magma.  I put in numbers suggested by the professor, but I do not know what the output I get means.

Comment: Didn't the professor show an example run of the index calculus algorithm?

Comment: Yes, and I have the code he used.  I can post the code he used here and say tell you what I did in magma so far, but I am having issues with not understanding what the output means and what to do with it.

Comment: I solved (a) by looking in my text book and doing a lot by hand, but I am not sure how to find the answer for (b).

Comment: Great! Good job. I have only ever done this (by hand) in a finite field like $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ for some relatively small $m$ as an exercise. I guess you are expected to check whether some of the relatively early reductions give residues with only small factors for a suitable definition of *small* :-)

Comment: If so minded you could copy/paste your calculations as an answer. That way the question gets some kind of a closure. Your call, of course.

Comment: Well, using magma to factor numbers from 100 to 10000000 I got a set of equations for which I was able to 2^k=B modp where B is a group of primes that factor into k while all being less than 13.  Using that, I had to solve using linear algebra and a matrix for k=a1*L(B1)+a2*L(B2)... mod(p-1) where B1 is the first prime in B, B2 the second, and a1 is the power that B1 was raised to etc.  So then solving for L(-1) L(2) L(3) L(5) L(7) L(11) and L(13), I then had to use magma to test and find a number j such that 2^j=x mod p-1, then find the factors that added to L(x) mod (p-1) and got the answer.